# Using hardware pixels (device dependent pixels) in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm developing a pixel-test web application that really need a 1-1 mapping between [hardware pixels](http://alistapart.com/article/a-pixel-identity-crisis/) and [reference pixels](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#length-units).

The app works fine on traditional 96dpi screens but when the pixel density goes above one, the app is useless. See this page on a hi-density screen for example: http://userpixel.com/testa2/#/pattern/hstripe/2

So when a div has a width of `1px` I want it to be really 1 pixel on all screens (retina, tv, kindle or any traditional screen). Or when I have a striped background image of 1px I want the stripes to be really 1px wide even on retina screens. See this page on a hi-density screen for example: http://userpixel.com/testa2/#/pixel/1px

Ideally I would add something to my CSS or HTML that makes all my code ignore `device-pixel-ratio`.

Comment: Use `<meta name="viewport">` with an `initial-scale`? I'm not sure what you're asking that can't easily be found with a simple internet search.

Comment: :D that would be too easy my friend. I'm not asking about meta viewport. The question is about how to work around the virtual pixels and get access to the hardware pixels. Read more here: http://alistapart.com/article/a-pixel-identity-crisis/ cheers

Comment: maybe you could scale everything on the screen depending on the `device-pixel-ratio`. Did you try that? E.g. setting up a media query with a device pixel ratio of 2 scales every part of the webpage 2 times. Then you'll need media queries for every expected pixel ratio though.

Comment: `Then you'll need media queries for every expected pixel ratio though` yeah that's the problem I'm trying to avoid. besides I don't want to scale everything on the page. Just part of it.